# Android listview header is ignoring height of its child layout

Tags: android, listview, header

Android listView header is ignoring height of its child layout.
In header I am using multiple layouts. When I set height macheparent to one of its child, listView totally ignores it.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. we dont have your code available, so we can't help. please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24845423) to include your code

Answer (score 0):

you can use weight and put them in a linear layout. that's simple!!